# Pandas groupby value and return observation count to dataset

Tags: python-3.x, pandas-groupby

I have a dataset like the following:

```
id    value
a      0
a      0
a      0
a      0
a      1
a      2
a      2
a      2
b      0
b      0
b      1
b      2
b      2
```

I want to groupby the "id" column and grab the number of observations in the "value" column, and return a new column in the original dataset that counts the number of times the "value" observation occurs within each id.

An example of the output I'm looking for is represented in column "output":

```
id    value    output
a      0        4
a      0        4 
a      0        4
a      0        4
a      1        1
a      2        3
a      2        3
a      2        3
b      0        2
b      0        2
b      1        1 
b      2        2
b      2        2
```

When grouping on id "a", there are 4 observations of 0, which is provided in the column "output" for each row that contains id of "a" and value of 0.

I have tried applications of groupby and apply, to no avail. Any suggestions would be very helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update: I figured out a solution for anyone who also faces this problem, and it works well.**

```
grouped = df.groupby(['id','value'])
df['output'] = grouped['value'].transform('count')
```

This will return the count of observations under each bucket and return that count to each observation that meets that criteria, as shown in the "output" column above.

Answer (score 0):

group by id and and value then count value.

```
data.groupby(['id' , 'value'])['id'].transform('count')
```

Comment: This isn't what I'm looking for. The groupby to get the counts is straightforward. What I'm looking to do then is to transfer those counts back into the original dataframe, so that for every entry that has id "a" and value 0, for example, the "output" column will be that count developed in the groupby count statement. Does that make sense?